# Create an SQL Select which counts from Sysdate to 2012

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I currently try to create an SQL Query which i wanna use in an Apex select list.

I just need to Count from This Year(Sysdate, in this format --> YYYY) to 2012.

The Result should be something like this:

```
A1
-----
2021
2020
2019
2018
2017
2016
2015
2014
2013
2012
```

My Attempt:

```sql
select a1 from
(
SELECT to_char(SYSDATE,'YYYY') a1 FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT to_char(add_months(SYSDATE,-12),'YYYY') FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT to_char(add_months(SYSDATE,-24),'YYYY') FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT to_char(add_months(SYSDATE,-36),'YYYY') FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT to_char(add_months(SYSDATE,-48),'YYYY') FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT to_char(add_months(SYSDATE,-60),'YYYY') FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT to_char(add_months(SYSDATE,-72),'YYYY') FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT to_char(add_months(SYSDATE,-84),'YYYY') FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT to_char(add_months(SYSDATE,-96),'YYYY') FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT to_char(add_months(SYSDATE,-108),'YYYY') FROM dual
) a
```

but this is Hardcoded and i would need to change it year for year.

or this example but this is PLSQL and i need it in SQL

```sql
Declare v_counter Number;
begin    
    a1:= to_char(Sysdate, 'YYYY');
    dbms_output.put_line(a1);
    While a1 > 2014 loop
    a1 := a1-1;
    dbms_output.put_line(a1);
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statement for your table(s); the DML (`INSERT`) statements for some sample data that is representative of the problem; a complete description of the problem; **YOUR** attempt to solve the problem; the errors/issues with **YOUR** solution; and the expected output. StackOverflow is not a code-writing service; you need to demonstrate an amount of effort first.

Comment: Your totaly right, im sorry for keeping it this short, this was my first post ever and i will try to make it as clear as possible and with enough soultion attempts in the first Message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first you can select consecutive 10 numbers from dual by below query:

```
select level from dual connect by level<=10;
```

Then I have just subtracted the numbers from current date's year to get  all the consecutive years. In where clause I have extracted the year from sysddate and subtract 2012 from it to get numbers of year to be published. Use below query to achieve what you are looking for.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY')-LEVEL+1 as A1 FROM
DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (select extract(year from sysdate)-2012 from dual)+1
order by A1
```

Comment: Thank you it worked as i wished, i never used "Connect By" or "Level" and i am currently reading up on it to get better :)